# Shell Bash : Check if I have all the software has the good version

Tags: bash, function, shell, testing, version

I want to check if all laptops have the good software version before to install and config a tool.

I need to extract and compare versions below:

- node
- npm
- java
- git
- Visual Studio Code
- python

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash


# Couleur pour mieux voir les reponses
NOCOLOR='\033[0m'
RED='\033[0;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'


# Version des sofwares
version_Nodejs=`node --version | cut -c 2-6`


parse_yaml() {
   local prefix=$2
   local s='[[:space:]]*' w='[a-zA-Z0-9_]*' fs=$(echo @|tr @ '\034')
   sed -ne "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\"\(.*\)\"$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p" \
        -e "s|^\($s\)\($w\)$s:$s\(.*\)$s\$|\1$fs\2$fs\3|p"  $1 |
   awk -F$fs '{
      indent = length($1)/2;
      vname[indent] = $2;
      for (i in vname) {if (i > indent) {delete vname[i]}}
      if (length($3) > 0) {
         vn=""; for (i=0; i<indent; i++) {vn=(vn)(vname[i])("_")}
         printf("%s%s%s=\"%s\"\n", "'$prefix'",vn, $2, $3);
      }i
   }'
}

eval $(parse_yaml config.yml "config_")

function verification_version() {
if [ $2 -eq $3 ]
echo $2
echo $3
then
    echo -e "The version installed on your machine ${MACHINE} for $1 is $GREEN $version_Nodejs that is correct. $NOCOLOR"
else
    echo - e "The version installed for $1 is $RED not correct $NOCOLOR. Create a Service Now request to ask to have $1 $2 minumum on your machine ${MACHINE} "
    # echo - e "$RED For Zowe CLI Call the support $NOCOLOR"
    exit 1
fi
}


# Verification des versions des Softwares
verification_version $config_NODEJS $version_Nodejs $config_VNODE
```

On my config.yml file

```
---
NODEJS: NodeJs
VNODE: 16.20
```

When I run it I have this

```
$ ./Init_VDIcopy.sh 
./Init_VDIcopy.sh: line 34: [: 16.15: integer expression expected
16.15
16.20
The version installed on your machine  for NodeJs is  16.15 that is correct.
```

Comment: Can you simplify this to the smallest version that still has the same problem? For example, test for just one tool instead of all of them.

Comment: @BenjaminW. thanks a lot for you return. As you asked me to reduce the code I changed it and I complete with the result. As you can see. I must find how to change the expression in integer. do you have any Idea ?

Comment: I put version_Nodejs= printf "%.2f\n" $version_Nodejs on my code but that change nothing $ ./Init_VDIcopy.sh 
16.15
16.15
16.20
The version installed on your machine  for NodeJs is  16.15 that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the code on my function as below and that is better

```
function verification_version() {

[[ "${2}" == "${3}" ]] || { echo -e "The version installed for $1 is not correct. ; exit 1; }

"The version installed on your machine for $1 is correct."

}
```

We can close this case ;)
Thanks a lot for your help